# Looping through argument in bash script and grab all values before executing a function

Tags: bash

I want to create a script that accepts argument from command line and assign them to the internal variable as well as call a "function" when appropriate.

Let's say that I have a bash script with the following:

```
test1(){
 echo "this is a test"
 if [ -z $var1 ]; then echo $var1 fi
 if [ -z $var2 ]; then echo $var2 fi
}

usage(){
 echo "to use this script you need arguments 1 and 2".
}

var1=""
var2=""

# Loop to read options and arguments
while [ $1 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        '-h') usage;;
        '-1') var1="$2";;
        '-2') var2="$2";;
        '-c') test1;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

I'd like my bash script to read all the arguments supplied and assign them to the internal variable then execute any function associated.
Let's say the below input:

```
INPUT: mybash -c -1="xxxxx" -2="ccccc" 
OUTPUT: test1 is executed without -1 and -2 to supply the value 
EXPECTED OUTPUT: test1 is executed after -1 and -2 have valorised var1 and var2
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're missing `;;` after two of your cases. You might also need to do an extra `shift` for the `-[12]` cases. Aside from that, what you're asking is a little unclear - example inputs and expected outputs might help clarify that...

Comment: Hi twalberb, thanks for the input. I wrote the bit of code above while commuting, hence the inaccuracy I will fix. As for the input, say I will pass mybash -c -1="xxx" -2="yyyy", I would expect my code to parse all the input parameters and assign the value to the internal variable for all supplied arguments, then execute whatever function connected to -c. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Perhaps you ought to `echo ${1}` before your `case` statement to see what you're actually processing. Hint: passing `-1="xxxx"` on your command line, you will not match `-1`, or indeed, any of the other cases, since `-1` is not the same as `-1="xxxx"`, and you have not defined a default case to handle strings that don't match anything else. You might also want to look into `getopts`, as it seems you're expecting to somehow split `-1="xxxx"` into `-1` and `"xxxx"`, but the shell doesn't do that automatically...

Comment: well -1 was the name of my parameter. Is this not the way to call params? I edited the question to make my requirements clear.

Comment: The arguments that get passed to your script get split on white-space, and then nothing else. So, if you do `myscript -1="xxxx"`, your script sees one argument (`$1`) with the contents `-1="xxxx"`. It does not see it as an option (`-1`) with a separate argument (`"xxxx"`) - you'll need to do that sort of parsing yourself. `getopts` and the string processing capabilities of the shell can help with that.